# How to disable sorting for few rows in asp.net gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, aspxgridview, gridview-sorting

Hi i'm showing some data in gridview which is sortable. I want to disable sorting for few rows based when date is not null.

below is the code

```
  griddata.datasource = dt;
    griddata.databind();
    if(condtion...)
     griddata.Rows[2].Enabled = false;
     griddata.Rows[3].Enabled = false;
```

but this is not working.With this code i can still able to sort.Please help me out.

Comment: What do you mean by disabling sort for certain rows? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @SelimYıldız I have a grid that consist of some rows.In that grid one date column is there.If a row have date value then i don't want to sort that row.If not i want to sort that row.